# Filter contents with brackets into a Python list

Tags: python, regex

I have tried to filter the content within the round brackets with regex.

```
s = "(time.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND car.Audi > 5) AND (time.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND car.VW > 5) OR (time.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND car.BMW > 5)"
```

What I would like to have as a return is a list of these contents and the ANDs

```
list = [
         "(time.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND car.Audi > 5)",
         "AND",
         "(time.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND car.VW > 5)",
         "OR",
         "(time.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND car.BMW > 5)"
        ]
```

I tried `re.split(r'\)\s*(AND|OR)\s*\(', s)` but some of the brackets were removed.

```
[
"(events.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND event_type.engine_error > 5",
 'AND', 
"events.timestamp > '2019-12-04 10:16:57+0100' AND event_type.turtle_lamp > 5)",
 ...
]
```

have you an idea how I can solve it best?

it doesn't have to be solved with Regex either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are removed because they are part of the *consuming* pattern. All consumed chars that are not captured are removed with `re.split`.

Wrap the parentheses with lookarounds, a lookbehind at the start and a lookahead at the end:

```
re.split(r'(?<=\))\s*(AND|OR)\s*(?=\()', s)
           ^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^
```

Now, `(?<=\))` matches a *location* that is immediately preceded with `)` and `(?=\()` matches a location immediately followed with `(`.